# What is the best practice to implement a delay to for loop with async function

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

here's the code I currently using,

```
function loopArrayWithAsync(array, doSthWithElement, finalCallback) {
    var count = 0;
    var _data = [];
    var _errs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        doSthWithElement(array[i], function (err, data) {
            count++;
            if (err) {
                _errs.push(err);
            }
            if (data) {
                _data.push(data);
            }
            if (count === data.length) {
                finalCallback(_errs, _data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then, I will use the function in this way:

```
loopArrayWithAsync(array, function (element, finish) {
    // element - element in the array
    asyncFunc(element, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            finish(err);
        } else {
            finish(null, result);
        }
    });
}, function (errs, finalData) {
    // when the for loop is finished,
    // i.e. (count === data.length)
    // this callback will be executed
    // errs - array of err from the above callback function
    // finalData - array of result from the above callback function
    outerCallback(errs, finalData);
});
```

with this implementation, I can loop through an array with async function and execute the callback function when all elements in the array have been processed.

but now I want to add a delay/interval feature to loopArrayWithAsync()

something like `loopArrayWithAsync(array, {interval : 1000}, function (element, finish) {...`, after it processed the first element, it should wait for 1000ms, then starts to process the second element, and vice versa...

I've found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop) talking about adding delay to for loop

but it seems to be more complicated while dealing with async functions.

Any answers will be appreciated

============================== update ==============================

this is the function after refactoring,

```
function loopArrayWithAsync(array, options, doSthWithElement, finalCallback) {
    if (isFunction(options)) {
        finalCallback = doSthWithElement;
        doSthWithElement = options;
        options = {};
    }
    options.interval = options.interval || 0;
    options.oneByOne = options.oneByOne || false;
    var _data = [];
    var _errs = [];
    var count = 0;
    var length = array.length;
    var i = 0;
    (function handleIteration() {
        if (i < length) {
            var element = array[i];
            doSthWithElement(element, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    _errs.push(err);
                }
                if (data) {
                    _data.push(data);
                }
                count++;
                if (count === length) {
                    finalCallback(_errs, _data);
                } else if (options.oneByOne) {
                    if (options.interval) {
                        setTimeout(handleIteration, options.interval);
                    } else {
                        process.nextTick(handleIteration);
                    }
                }
            });
            i++;
            if (!options.oneByOne) {
                if (options.interval) {
                    setTimeout(handleIteration, options.interval);
                } else {
                    process.nextTick(handleIteration);
                }
            }
        }
    }());
};
```

so that I can use the function in this way now:

```
loopArrayWithAsync(array, {interval : 1000}, function (element, finish) {
    asyncFunc(element, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            finish(err);
        } else {
            anotherAsyncFunc(result, function (err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    finish(err);
                } else {
                    finish(null, doc);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}, function (errs, finalData) {
    outerCallback(errs, finalData);
});
```

or

`loopArrayWithAsync(array, {oneByOne : true}, function (element, finish) {...`
loop through the elements one by one

`loopArrayWithAsync(array, {interval : 5000, oneByOne : true}, function (element, finish) {...`
loop through the elements one by one and with 5 seconds delay

available options :

`interval` is the amount of milliseconds between each iteration, default : `0`

If `oneByOne` is true, the method would only proceed to the next element until `finish` has been invoked for the current element, default : `false`

The code suits my case now, but I will still try the suggested libraries to make life easier, thank you

Please leave a comment if you found that the code can be further improved, looking forward to any suggestions!

Comment: Why don't use Promises? For example, [bluebird's `map`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#mapfunction-mapper--object-options---promise) does what you want.

Comment: @thefourtheye Thank you for pointing me to bluebird. I didn't know about that. But, if a lib is an option, I would suggest to use async:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#each

Comment: it seems not bad, I will study it in the future, thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local function to make the asynchronous loop. For the next iteration the function calls itself with a delay:

```
function loopArrayWithAsync(array, doSthWithElement, finalCallback, delay) {
  var _data = [], _errs = [], i = 0;
  loop();

  function loop() {
    doSthWithElement(array[i], function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        _errs.push(err);
      }
      if (data) {
        _data.push(data);
      }
      i++;
      if (i === array.length) {
        finalCallback(_errs, _data);
      } else {
        window.setTimeout(loop, delay);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

To start the calls at a certain interval instead of having a delay between calls, just use `setInterval` with different times:

```
function loopArrayWithAsync(array, doSthWithElement, finalCallback, delay) {
  var _data = [], _errs = [], count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      doSthWithElement(array[i], function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          _errs.push(err);
        }
        if (data) {
          _data.push(data);
        }
        count++;
        if (count === array.length) {
          finalCallback(_errs, _data);
        }
      });
    }, i * delay);
  }
}
```

Comment: this may works in most situations, but there is a problem, what if my `asyncFunc()` needs more time than `delay`? The next iteration will never start until `asyncFunc()` called `finish`.

Comment: @kitz17: The delay is from the finish of one call to the start of the next. If you just want to make new calls at a certain interval, regardless of whether the previous call has finished, that is easier. Just use `setTimeout` with a delay of `i * delay` to start them at different times. I added an example above.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @thefourtheye you can use the concept of `Promises`, and [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) is a fast and good library for this. `Promise.settle` lets you resolve and reject your promises and then inspect the result.

```
function loopArray(array) {
    var arrayOfPromises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        arrayOfPromises.push(doSomethingAsync(array[i]));
    }

    Promise.settle(arrayOfPromises).then(function (results) {
        console.log("All async calls done! You can inspect the result!");
        console.log(results);
    });
}


function doSomethingAsync(item) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        //Do you async work here!
        console.log("Entering async function call " + item);
        if(item === "three"){
            reject("bad value!");
        }
        resolve(item + " promise done!");
    });
}


loopArray(["one","two","three"]);
```

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ngs1w29/) of the below example. Working with asynchronous functions, promises can help you out a lot, so I'd really suggest you look into it.

Comment: And if there's a better choice than `Promise.settle`, please post a comment!